# Answer Questions!

Tags: visual, rebus

Here I have another easy but pretty REBUS for you guys, but it was fun creating on Paint.

[image]

All the Best!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's

> A newspaper!

Because

> What's black and white and red all over?
>
>  (There are "what"s, which are black and white, and "all over" is colored red. This is an old riddle, the most common answer to which is "a newspaper" (because the newspaper is black ink on white paper, and "red" is homophonous with (past tense) "read", but many jokey answers (*"A skunk in a paint store!"*) have been formulated since the riddle's inception)

Comment: Can't accept it already. Why do you have to be such a brainiac. :D

Comment: (I'm on my phone or I would have gone into slightly better detail)

Answer (score -1):

> Everybody knows that old joke we used to tell in elementary school, "Whats black and white and red all over?" answers, a zebra(or penguin) in a blender, or a newspaper!